# How to expose mysql port?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I'm trying to expose the port `3310` to allow remote `MySQL` connection. So far, I have this configuration:

```
  database:
    container_name: sfapi_db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3310:3306
    build:
      context: ./docker/database
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_NAME}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PWD}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PWD_ROOT}
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
      - type: bind
        source: ./docker/database/my.cnf
        target: /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

and this is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM mariadb:latest

CMD ["mysqld"]

EXPOSE 3310
```

here the my.cnf:

```
[client-server]
# Port or socket location where to connect
port = 3310
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

when I run `docker-compose up --build -d` and access to the container list, I get:

[image]

I also opened the port on the server using `sudo ufw allow 3310`. Also, I cannot use the port 3306 'cause it's used by another container, that's why I'm using 3310.

For some reason, when I go [there](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) and check if the port 3310 is opened, I always get that is closed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The first thing I'd try is deleting the custom image and MySQL configuration.  Run the unmodified `image: mariadb` without the `my.cnf` mount.  The database will start listening on the normal port 3306; then the `ports: [3310:3306]` line should map that to port 3310 on the host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `my.cnf` resides in the container. Then the port used should be `3306`

```
[client-server]
# Port or socket location where to connect
port = 3306
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Since in the context of the container, this is the port that exposes mysql.

So what probably happens is that you expose `3306` but the container has assigned `3310` for the mysql server. Thus 3306 is indeed closed.

Comment: This.  You can also map to ports 3310:3310 instead because your MySQL is actually listening on 3310 as per your my.cnf.  The first 3310 is on your host machine, the second is the container.